# Scene Limit Exceeds: Triangles

Tags: decentraland

Recently try to develop using decentraland sdk. I have downloaded some assets from sketchfab and copy those files into my decentraland project.

However, when I click start the project using `dcl start`. After rendering, I saw a warning message on the browser rendering page. How can I fix that?

`Scene Limit Exceeds: Triangles(1918731/10000)`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the `Entity` importing from the `.glb` file have too many "faces". By open the `.glb` file in [blender](https://www.blender.org/), you can modify the `.glb` file and decreasing the amount of "faces" (eg. make a low-poly version for it).